# How to fix application isn't responding (ANR) in Android

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I have one application and created this this **support library**!
After migrate to **AndroidX** , when application running after some time show me **application isn't responding**!

**My profile tab image :** https://i.ibb.co/41ZMP2Q/17.png

How can I know why show me this error?!

I have 3 services, because I have screen recorder app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".tester.services.FloatingControlService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
        tools:targetApi="q" />
    <service
        android:name=".tester.tests_steps.FloatingLayoutService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
        tools:targetApi="q" />
    <service
        android:name=".tester.services.RecorderService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
        tools:targetApi="q" />
```

My locgat image : https://i.ibb.co/6gfNyDt/18.png

How can I find why show me this error???

Comment: We cannot answer this question without seeing the ANR Stack Trace and any code that might be referred to within that stack trace.

Comment: @KenY-N , yes my friend. but how can I see my ANR Stack Trace . I can't see any log for this in LogCat ! :(

Comment: @KenY-N please see this url : https://i.ibb.co/6gfNyDt/18.png not show me any log for this !

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#pull_a_traces_file for how to pull the ANR traces